# Why we use 1000 to divide our fees?

Tags: solidity, fees, erc-223

```
function transferToAddress(address _to, uint _value, bytes memory _data) internal returns (bool success) {
        require (_to != msg.sender && _to != address(0));
        uint fee = calculateFee(_value);
        require (_value > 0);
        require (balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
        require (balances[_to].add(_value) >= balances[_to]);
        uint sendAmount = _value.sub(fee);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(sendAmount);
        if (fee > 0) {
            balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(fee);
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, owner, fee,_data);
        }
        holderIsExist(_to);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }


function calculateFee(uint _amount)public view returns(uint){
            uint fee = (_amount.mul(basisPointsRate)).div(1000);
            if (fee > maximumFee) {
                    fee = maximumFee;
            }
            if (fee < minimumFee) {
                fee = minimumFee;
            }
            return fee;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not about why divide by 1000. This can be any no raised to power 10.
The reason behind such division is

> You can not use decimals in smart contracts

and hence what if you want to have have x % of fee ?

You need to use logic

```
fee = amount * x / 100;
```

But them the min value of x is 1. So if you want your x to be as low as 0.1, you can use:

```
fee = amount * x / 1000;
```

So when you need fee to be 10 % in later case you need to use x = 100.

This is similar to why we have decimals in ERC-20 tokens.

**Suggestion**

My personal prefrence to have such divisions is use a combination of 2 values.

- basisPointsRate_N (Numerator)
- basisPointsRate_D (Denominator)

> fee = amount * basisPointsRate_N / basisPointsRate_D

Now you can set whatever min values you want.